# reduce(x+y, xs) and sum(xs) are not equivalent in python?

Tags: python, sum, tuples, reduce, equational-reasoning

I would expect the two to mean the same, from a functional equational standpoint, however:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = ['a', 'b', 'c']

reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, zip(x, y))  # works

sum(zip(x, y))  # fails
```

Why is `sum` failing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The actual problem is, with the `sum`'s default start value. Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum),

> Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns the total. **start defaults to `0`**. The iterable‘s items are normally numbers, and the start value is not allowed to be a string.

But, in case of `reduce`, if no optional start value is given, it will use the first value in the iterable as the initializer. So, `reduce` is actually evaluating it like this

```
( ( (1, 'a') + (2, 'b') ) + (3, 'c') )
```

Since `sum` assumes start value as 0, it evaluates it like this,

```
0 + (1, 'a') + (2, 'b') + (3, 'c')
```

In this case, it tries to add `0` with a tuple and that is why you are getting

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

To fix this, pass an empty tuple, to `sum`'s start, like this

```
>>> sum(zip(x, y), tuple())
(1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c')
```

Now, with the initial value being an empty tuple, the evaluation happens like this

```
() + (1, 'a') + (2, 'b') + (3, 'c')
```

**Note:** In both these case, there will be more than one intermediate tuples created. To avoid that, I would recommend flattening the data and pass it to `tuple` constructor as a generator expression, like this

```
>>> tuple(item for items in zip(x, y) for item in items)
(1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c')
```

Comment: This makes one think that `sum` is actually mis-designed: `start` should default to the first item rather than to `0`.

Comment: @thefourtheye Ah, very good catch, about the initial value; I didn't know you could pass a custom start value. For `sum(zip(x, y), tuple())` I am still getting "TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type". Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @georg What would `sum([])` be then?

Comment: @Joel: well, because `sum` is not generic `reduce`, it would be fair to return 0 for empty arguments. But if the args is not empty, it makes no sense to default to 0.

Comment: @HenryHenrinson `TypeError` with `reduce` or `sum`?

Comment: @thefourtheye with sum, for the expression: `sum(zip(x, y), tuple())`. Reduce works just fine.

Comment: @HenryHenrinson Which version of Python you are using? I tried in Py 2.7 and 3.4 Both are working fine

Comment: @thefourtheye 2.7. If I set `x=[1,2,3]; y=[2,3,4]`, sum works just fine. It's only when I switch to `y=['a','b','c']` that this fails.

Comment: @thefourtheye I think there's something weird about my environment, then; something I'm importing might be overriding `sum` (not 100% sure). Thanks for your help, though.